# Search query builder filter on "Now"

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

I'm using search results web part and try to filter result based on current date and time.

I can use `Today` to filter results on today's date but I want to use time as well.

I am using a pre configured managed property `RefinableDateTime00`